# How is mpeg interleaved?

Tags: audio, video, multiplexing

I need to know after how many frames of video the audio part starts for an mpeg file.
So for example, first there are 5 frames of video and after that there are 10 audio samples.
This would be repeated for the whole file.

Extra: Is there a way to set this information in ffmpeg?

EDIT: more information

I have a video stream in RGBA format. These frames are written to the encoder.
I also have an audio stream in s16le format which I want to feed to the encoder.

If I use the video stream in RGBA format and add a regular .wav file to it as audio everything works fine. However, I need to add my own audio stream. When I try to do this I get no audio and the video is broken. It slides from right to left and top to bottom. The part of the frame that falls of is rendered at the other side (for example, the frame is 20px to the right, the 20px that fell of is rendered at the left side).

I think that I have to find in which order I have to write my audio stream to the encoder. This part from the console command manages my audio:

```
-f s16le -ac 1 -i -
```

When I tried it with a regular .wav file I just wrote

```
-i file_name.wav
```

I hope this makes it a bit clearer.

FURTHER EDIT:

I'm currently writing 18 frames to the encoder and after that I write 18 frames worth of audio samples to the encoder. This repeats. If I go to a lower frequency of this I get green flashes in the video

FFMPEG COMMAND:

```
ffmpeg -r 24 -pix_fmt rgba -s 1280x720 -f rawvideo -y -i - -f s16le -ac 1 -i - -vf vflip -vcodec mpeg1video -qscale 4 -bufsize 500KB -maxrate 5000KB OUTPUT_FILE
```

Comment: Your question is not very clear.  First of all you say MPEG, but MPEG itself is not a format, its a working group.  There are dozens of formats published by MPEG, we need to know which one you're talking about.  Also, can you add any other details to your question, in general it doesn't make much sense.

Comment: I added some more information. I hope it's clearer now

Comment: Are you writing both the video and audio to stdin?

Comment: I'm using `fwrite()` to write the audio and the video

Comment: Can you share your full FFMPEG command line?

Comment: Added the command to the question

Comment: How is your video being passed to FFMPEG?  You're not providing any arguement to `-i`.

Comment: Woops, that's a typo. It should be a `-` (changed it in the question)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21039/discussion-between-heavyd-and-dries).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are writing both the audio and video data to the same input stream.  FFMPEG needs to have the two stream separated so it can multiplex them properly.  I would look into using named pipes for passing two separate streams to FFMPEG.  Something like this:

```
ffmpeg -r 24 -pix_fmt rgba -s 1280x720 -f rawvideo -y -i \\.\pipe\videopipe -f s16le -ac 1 -i \\.\pipe\audiopipe -vf vflip -vcodec mpeg1video -qscale 4 -bufsize 500KB -maxrate 5000KB OUTPUT_FILE
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not thing theres a general rule for this. It can be like V0 A0 V1 A1 V2 A2 or V0 V1 A01 V2 V3 A23. The exactly of this should be dependent on the compression and quality of both video and audio.
The only actual rule is that both the video stream of frames (V0 V1, etc) and the corresponding audio stream of blocks (A0, A1, etc) have to be integers.

Comment: I did that at first, interleaving the video per frame with the number of sound samples I need but that gives weird results

Comment: But what are you trying to do ? Maybe you don't have to dig that deep.

Comment: I'm trying to manually add the audio I have in s16le format to the encoder. The video is written per frame to the encoder as well. I need to get the order right in which I send the data so the encoder can put it in the mpeg file in the right order

Comment: So you want to do it like this because you need to keep 16 bit PCM samples instead of 24 bit or 32 bit ones ? If 16-bit samples are not a requirement, then it will be a lot more easy to just convert the video and audio into two well known widely-used formats and then any decent re-encoding software can sync them.

Comment: I don't need to keep that format no. It seemed like an easy test. These video and audio things are streams btw, it's not like I can convert both to another file first to make it easier. So no, 16-bit is not required but that's the size per audio sample I have right now (but this can be changed). I NEED to do this using ffmpeg though since this function is included in my application